# Outputting the location to the sms

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-location

I am trying to output the location received from the gps/network into the sms. I have tried using geocode and used try catch for the List, but I need help to output the getAddressLine into the Button setOnClickListener. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //conversion
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bp = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bp);
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();
    final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try{
            List<Address> address;
            address = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            Address ad = address.get(0);
                  StringBuffer geo = new StringBuffer();
            geo = geo.append(ad.getAddressLine(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //ends here
    LocationListener ll = new LocationListener(){
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Location", location.toString());
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
```

And the code for the button

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent loc = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            loc.putExtra("sms_body", geo);
            loc.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(loc);
        }
    });
```

I wanted to show the output on the loc.putExtra for the intent.

Comment: if i use locationmanager.toString() i get an output android.location.LocationManager@44ee7718. I want to show an output like Los Angeles, CA 90501.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the `geo` variable locally in the try/catch block: you'll need to move that to a global of some sort, so the `geo` variable actually exists when you click the button.

If you do that (and if your `Geocoder` instance is working correctly) that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I got up to
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
  List<Address> addresses = null;
         try{
          addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        final String ad = address.getAddressLine(0);

and it gives me no error when I put ad in the putExtra, but the app does not run... any other ideas?

Comment: Does not run? what errors does it produce in the Android log files? Does it crash with an exception?

Comment: sorry im new to the android programming. when i run the emulator and run my app it gives me an error, the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again. and i do not see any errors in the code... how do i see the error?

Comment: it shows like this...
05-07 17:59:39.279: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-07 17:59:39.299: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 17:59:39.299: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sd/com.example.sd.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 17:59:39.299: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: SO, you have a different error: you'll need to look for the line number that the NullPointer refers to and fix that before you can go any further.

Comment: hmm... how do i do that...?

Comment: i actually got it to work... but just having a trouble with outputting it into the sms body

Comment: Try `Intent loc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); loc.setData(Uri.parse("sms:")); loc.putExtra("sms_body", geo); startActivity(loc);` and see if that works?